# Signed Setup: UAC yellow

Tags: code-signing, uac

I've transferred a Installshield 2011 (Because the Licence is so expensive, boss won't by a new one next time) from XP to Windows 8.1.

Because signing the msi [will crash Installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406992/installshield-2011-crashes-at-build-between-embedding-manifest-and-signing#51635023), I signed the msi in a [post-build event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51635023/6448689).

But starting setup will prompt [the yellow dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd835561(v=ws.10)). But when signing with Installshield in XP, the UAC is blue. Aaaand (the interesting part): After looking into the signature (showing the msi-file properties / digital signature / Details) the UAC is blue! (Tested on Windows 7). The [/ac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701672/6448689) did not helped.

What can I do? Can anyone describe what happens?

Edit:

This is my Command line

```
"(somewere)\Signtool.exe" sign /f "(otherwere)\ext.pfx" /p XXX /d "YYYY" /du "ZZZZ" /tr "http://timestamp.comodoca.com" /a "(nowhere)\AAAA.msi" "(nowhere)\Setup.exe"
```

I'm using a SignTool version from one of the latest SDKs